# What is prevCount in this code from React Hooks reference?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

Trying to learn React Hooks and new to coding in general and I noticed prevCount is not declared beforehand. What is the value of prevCount and how come you do not have to declare it beforehand like const prevCount? I do not understand where this came from, is it just a variable you declare in setCount or useState that accesses the default value (in this case, initialCount) of count?

```
  const [count, setCount] = useState(initialCount);
  return (
    <>
      Count: {count}
      <button onClick={() => setCount(initialCount)}>Reset</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(prevCount => prevCount - 1)}>-</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)}>+</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html

Answer (score 4):

prevCount refers the value of `count` at the time of evaluation. In practice, lets take a look a modification of your example:

```
function TestCompononent() {
  const initialCount = 0;
  const [count, setCount] = useState(initialCount);

  function handleChange1() {
    setCount(count + 1)
  }

  function handleChange2() {
    setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)
  }

  function handleChange3() {
    setCount(count + 1)
    setCount(count + 1)
  }

  function handleChange4() {
    setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)
    setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)
  }

  return (
    <>
      Count: {count}
      <button onClick={() => setCount(initialCount)}>Reset</button>
      <button onClick={handleChange1}>handleChange1</button>
      <button onClick={handleChange2}>handleChange2</button>
      <button onClick={handleChange3}>handleChange3</button>
      <button onClick={handleChange4}>handleChange4</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Ok, so now in this example, `handleChange1` and `handleChange2` will behave identically, BUT `handleChange3` and `handleChange4` will not.

Let's imagine when we call `handleChange3` that we haven't done anything else, so `count` is equal to `0`.

When we call `handleChange3` we are doing

```
setCout(count + 1) // count === 0
setCout(count + 1) // count === 0
```

which means that at the next render cycle, count will equal `1`

In the same scenario, if we called `handleChange4` instead, we would be doing

```
setCout((prevCount) => prevCount + 1) // prevCount === 0
setCout((prevCoutn) => prevCount + 1) // prevCount === 1
```

which means that at the next render cycle, count will equal `2`

Hope that helps illustrate what's going on :)

Answer (score 2):

Official [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html) contains bit of information as you have pasted the link in there

> The function will receive the previous value, and return an updated value

`prevCount` - is a `functional` scope `variable`, updated with the callback function. You don't define these variables as they exist and die within the function and have no meaning out of it. I

The click will update the state using the previous state using a callback. `prevCount`is is the most recent value of count.

Answer (score 1):

the prevCount it is the current value of your state before set new value to your state
so if state was 1 and click on button that sum 1 to old value that mean
old=>old+1
equal
1=>1+1
that will return 2

Answer (score 0):

With respect to your scenario:

1. When the '+' or '-' button is clicked, the setCount function is called.
2. This function is by default passed with an argument 'prevCount' that always refers to the previous value held by the count variable (.i.e, the state variable).
3. In such a way, the function makes sure that it always correctly increment/decrement the previously held value of the state variable.

**Note:** It's crucial to note that in this way it prevents React from batching the updates as showed in handleChange3 function in [@joe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5552874/joe-lissner)'s example.